# Programmatically Generate Personal Access Token for VSTS

Tags: c#, azure-devops

Is there are VSTS REST endpoint I can connect to in order to let a user self-serve themselves another PAT?  Ideally a few days before their current one expires. I have a time sheet application that is now connecting to VSTS to get Workitem information and to update said Workitem. However, at some point (90 days, 180 days or a year later) the PAT will expire.  I would rather them not have to leave the application to generate a new one and save it in my application at each interval. I would love for them to just click a button to generate it again from my app. It would be secure seeing that I would connect to the REST endpoint with their current PAT.

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing as it would defeat the purpose of expiry by making any token virtually permanent.

Comment: True. But in the context of a specific app that is controlling your access to begin with, it is really only a conduit to more data that has only the hurdle of needing a PAT. I knew it was a long shot, but thought I would try.  Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn’t official API to get Personal Access Token programmatically.

You may consider OAuth: [Authorize access to REST APIs with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=vsts)

Comment: At least the benefit of a PAT is that it is tied to a person.  I would rather not have comments and time added via a system account or some made up/non-actual user account.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: @Grandizer In my opinion, just work with PAT, it's hard to track the change history, because you don't know who made the change actually.

Comment: Is it possible with MS Graph api? I mean i use same credential in MS Teams and Azure DevOps, so i am curious that is it possible with MS Grpah api?