# Create Personal Access Token in C# or Powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

Hello I'm working with Azure Devops and I have a CI/CD pipeline which uses Deployment Groups. After creating my deployment group the web UI generated a powershell script that you can leverage to install the agents on whatever nodes you want to add to the deployment group. I also clicked on the check box that generates the PAT token that can be passed in as an argument for the agent installation.

I'd like to automate all of this in a powershell script which, in this case would be to simply copy and paste the powershell cmds, that the Web UI generates, into my own script. The problem is that I can't find anything online about generating a PAT token in powershell.

Can someone tell me if it's even possible to generate a PAT token programmatically which I can then use to install the agent?

Comment: What have you tried? It would be good if you provided sample of your attempt at this.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear that this can be accomplished in a programmatic manner. See the following post for details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/50870641/3858673

Also note that the [API only supports listing a users available PATs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/tokenadmin/personal%20access%20tokens?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)

However, the creation of the PAT only needs to be done once every 30-365 days. Once created, you should be able to pass it securely to your PowerShell script.

Answer (score 0):

Following code can help you out.

> ```
> $currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext;
> $azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile;
> $profileClient = New-Object 
> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azureRmProfile);
> $pat = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.Subscription.TenantId).AccessToken;
> Write-Output $pat
> ```

this is access token, not PAT but you can access all APIs using this access token.

Comment: I believe you have provided an example for an access token to the Azure Management APIs which do not provide access to Azure DevOps APIs.

Comment: Can you share a complete example with which you are able to register a deployment group agent?

Comment: This worked for me to access the ADO API rest endpoints using this output.  Not sure why it was marked -1, other than it's not an actual PAT token on the ADO org.  That being said, you can then use the rest endpoints to make programmatic changes in your ADO org.