# Getting Personal Access Token with Azure DevOps

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-rest-api

I have C# code that pulls data from Azure DevOps On-premise that executes with a service account with no problems.  The service account has Collection Admin Access through an AD Group.  My problem is the service account only needs read access.  What does the code look like to generate a PAT for the service account that limits the access to read only?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I'm still trying to write the code but it seems as if I should be able to do it based on this documentation below.  I dont know what the difference is between DevOps Service User and a DevOps Server user is though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#get-an-access-and-refresh-token-for-the-user

Comment: If you consider using OAuth, it can be achieved through code, but according to your question, PAT can not be generated programmatically. About the difference between Devops Service User and Devops Server user,you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/about-azure-devops-services-tfs?view=azure-devops#fundamental-differences-between-azure-devops-services-and-azure-devops-server).

Comment: @Hugh Lin, you are also right but he answered first. And Thank you, I thought "...Services" was an add on, not the cloud version of DevOps en premises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know this is not possible to create `PAT` programatically. You can check also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857066/programmatically-generate-personal-access-token-for-vsts). But if you want to define scope for `PAT` you can do at it's [creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page).